# pip tries to install dependencies of packages that are excluded by environment marker in requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I want to instruct pip to ignore certain OS-specific packages by using environment markers in requirements.txt. However, for some reason pip still tries to install dependencies mentioned in these packages:

```
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32==223->-r requirements.txt (line 61))
Ignoring pypiwin32: markers 'platform_system == "Windows"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pywin32: markers 'platform_system == "Windows"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pywinpty: markers 'platform_system == "Windows"' don't match your environment
```

If those dependencies happen to be OS-specific as well, the entire deployment fails.
Is there a way to force pip to skip ignore those dependencies as well?

This is the relevant section in the requirements file:

```
pypiwin32==223; platform_system == "Windows"
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==6.2.1
pipreqs==0.4.10
plotly==3.9.0
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
psutil==5.6.7
Pygments==2.4.2
pyrsistent==0.15.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-dotenv==0.10.1
python-pptx==0.6.18
pytz==2019.1
pywin32==227; platform_system == "Windows"
pywinpty==0.5.4; platform_system == "Windows"
```

Comment: Can wee see your entire instructions for `pip`? Is it some `requirements.txt`? Also I don't see `pip` trying to install these packages; exactly opposite — it skips them. "*entire deployment fails*" Can wee see your commands and the error?

Comment: The first line `Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32==223->-r requirements.txt (line 61))` tries to install a dependency.

Comment: Can you show the log of pip actually installing *the dependencies*? So far, the shown log only shows that pip is explicitly "**Ignoring** pypiwin32" (and others).

Comment: Doesn't "collecting" mean that it's getting installed? Unfortunately this is the only log I have access to - it doesn't actually show the success or failure of the installation, but I can tell from the result that non of the packages get installed. My sysadmin said after that this package is the likely reason for the failure.

Comment: I agree with @MisterMiyagi and @phd _collecting_ doesn't mean _install_. I believe _pip_ needs to figure out what the _markers_ are, so it somehow needs to access the _metadata_ for that library, which most likely means that something needs to be downloaded. I would think this could well be what happens in the _collecting_ phase. Additionaly, if I am not mistaken it is indeed _pip_'s behavior to fail the whole installation if one of the elements listed in `requirements.txt` can not be successfully installed.